# How can I add an image for FB status to fetch?

Tags: web-development, facebook

Typing any link on Facebook triggers an automated function that scans for images on a website. What I'm trying to do is to use an image for that sole purpose, which means I don't want it in my website but I want Facebook to display on status updates.

**Failed attempts so far:**

- IMG SRC combined with style:"display:none"
- IMG SRC combined with style:"visibility:hidden"
- IMG SRC combined with width="0" height="0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup your pages to use certain images by using [Facebook's Open Graph Meta's](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags) within the head of your site.

For Example:

```
<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.yoursite.co.uk/img/fb-image.jpg'/>
```

View the source of your page and ensure that if you have any plugins such as Yoast, AceSEF, SEF404SH or any other SEO plugin that injects Facebooks Metas into your pages automatically as you will need to disable it and manually input the images that you want to be used as the thumbnail.

Comment: This is the answer.  If you have more than one of these tags the user will be able to page through them.

Comment: It took a while but it worked.