# How to tell Facebook not to fetch specific images?

Tags: facebook

I posted a few days ago how it was possible to [tell FB to fetch specific images](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44340/how-can-i-add-an-image-for-fb-status-to-fetch) in my site for status updates.

I still need to tell it what not to fetch, since many of these pictures wouldn't represent the website very well. I'd really rather only show the site logo.

Comment: Great question! I often see when a site is shared that Facebook picks a banner ad as its image even though they come from a completely different domain! I'd imagine this would be very common and easy for them to avoid but the next best thing would be to find the answer to your question :)

Comment: If you use the og:url tag, you can specify which image is default, but the others will still show up as choices.  I'm not sure of a way to exclude images, unless you make them background images.

Comment: Have you considered robots.txt?

Comment: I think this will answer your question well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images-and-other-metadata-when-sharing-my-url

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want Facebook **NOT** show images they have scraped from your site (because they might be out of context) and want to know how to instruct them or simply stop them from doing it.

You can also just create a dynamic rule that will redirect any attempt to pull certain files back to a single file, sort of a "Neener Neener" kind of result to the requester. Either way, this [generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) might be useful. Especially if you always want them to get the same image like your logo no matter what "they" grab automatically.

Comment: FWIW, the "generator" linked above _cannot_ be used to _generate_ such a redirect. (That generator is only for specific rewrites.)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to cloak your page when the facebook scraper comes along.  It uses the user agent.

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

For that user agent, serve a version of the page with the images removed.

Answer (score 0):

There are apparently two ways of doing this and the best thing to do is to check out the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079599/facebook-post-link-image), but for quick reference, one or more `<link rel="image_src" href="..."/>` tags will keep FB in check (for now).

Comment: "two ways of doing this" - and what "two ways" are those? Please include the relevant (summarised) information in your answer, rather than just linking to another post/site. (The linked question has 12 answers - which answer are you referring to?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when Facebook grabbed avatars from my page, and I discovered that Facebook grabbed images that are largest. So if you want to show up only one image, for instance, make it bigger (I think 10px will be enough since it's a code that probably compare numbers, but this need to be tested).

Comment: "I think 10px will be enough" - but 10px is very small?! Or are you suggesting to make all the other images very small so that FB won't use them? (Although that is probably impractical.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this- `<meta property="og:image" content="http://yoursite/yourImage.jpg">`
It is Open graph protocol. http://ogp.me/ You decide which image Facebook will show.

Comment: You should explain *why* this is a useful answer